# How to create new migration on vs code in N-Tier project

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to create migration on my N-Tier project on VS Code, but when I select my Data project and run the command, I get the error below. Can you help me?

```
System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContextFromFactory(Type factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
```

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Comment: Have you manually defined any constructors for any of your models?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you have defined parametric constructor(s) for one (or more) of your model classes and hence prevented the compiler to automatically generate a default (parameter-less) constructor for your model class(es) and since entity framework needs a default constructor for every model class, it's throwing an exception.
What you need to do is to define a parameter-less constructor for every model that has a user-defined parametric constructor.